# What header should be sent by master when there are multiple slaves whose data is getting updated(Event triggered Frames)?

Tags: embedded, communication-protocol, autosar

We want to check Rx of data from slaves in case of Lin event triggered frames. According to our understanding, in Lin stack integration for Autosar, we have Tx and Rx of unconditional frames. Here the master sends a header based on PID(protected identifier) configured for TX and Rx frames by using ARTOP tool. When header sent by master matches with slave PID then that slave responds with a data. Where as in event triggered frames, master sends a header and more than one slaves  will respond for that header, only if thier data has got updated. If only a single slave responds then it will send its updated data but if more than one slave responds then there will be a collision and master will handle and resolve the collision.

Answer (score 0):

The *event triggered frame* header sent by the master consist in a group of *unconditional frame*s headers just packed, each one has the `PID` of one slave the master wants to poll, something like: `[Break:Sync:IDx:Break:Sync:IDy:Break:Sync:IDz:...]`, they are sent in a row.

After that, the protocol follows as you describe it.

Comment: That's not an answer. If you are not allowed to add comments why are you trying it via an answer which isn't one? You won't be allowed this either. It just east into your reputation which delays being able to add comments for even longer.